# Add brackets to year in philosophy-modern bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-philosophy

Using philosophy-modern, I would like to have the years in brackets, like [1972] and I have set up the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}  
\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}  
%
@book{davidson:1996,
    Author = {Kenneth R. Davidson},
    Publisher = {AMS},
    Title = {C$^{*}$-Algebras by Example},
    Year = {1996}}    
%
@article{choi:1980,
    Author = {Choi, Man-Duen},
    Journal = {J. Oper. Theory},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {271--285},
    Title = {Some assorted inequalities for positive linear maps on C$^{*}$--algebras},
    Volume = {4},
    Year = {1980}} 
%
\end{filecontents}  
\usepackage[%
    ,backend=biber
    ,style=philosophy-modern
    ,firstinits = true]{biblatex}  
%
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
        \iffieldundef{year}%
        {}%
        {\makebox[\bibhang][l]{%
            \hspace*{.5ex}%
                \printtext{\mkbibbrackets{\printfield{labelyear}\printfield{extrayear}}%
                \hskip\yeartitle}%
             }}}
%
\bibliography{testbib}      \begin{document}  
%
\nocite{*}  
\printbibliography      
\end{document}
```

Everything works fine but there are no brackets. Do I have to do something differently?

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`philosophy-modern` uses the macro `\postsepyear` to typeset the year in the bibliography.

Its original definition in `philosophy-modern.bbx` is

```
\renewcommand*{\postsepyear}[1]{%
  \printtext{\makebox[\bibhang][r]{%
    #1\hskip\yeartitle}}\nopunct}
```

We can add `\mkbibbrackets` in the right place

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
    ,backend=biber
    ,style=philosophy-modern
    ,giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\postsepyear}[1]{%
  \printtext{\makebox[\bibhang][r]{%
    \mkbibbrackets{#1}\hskip\yeartitle}}\nopunct}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{nussbaum,sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: References with year in square brackets]